# Using persistent screen buffer in OpenGL to optimize performance

Tags: python, performance, opengl, buffer, glut

I'm currently working on a Python program that uses 2D OpenGL graphics. It's mostly intended for use with large screen resolution and a relatively slow computer, so, while it's all working fine, it could use some performance gain by optimizing the graphics.

So here's what I've got: the screen background is formed from multiple images on program startup, and never changes afterwards. So, I'm wondering if it is possible to write the resulting screen data into a buffer, which is then constantly used in the main drawing loop, to bypass all the functions involved in drawing the background.

So here's what I'd like to do:

```
def drawBackground(self):  #Called once on startup
    for item in BackObjects:
        item.draw()
    # [CODE HERE] Writing the screen pixel data to a buffer (a lower layer?)

def drawObjects(self):  #Called in the main drawing loop
    # [CODE HERE] Clear the buffer (possibly only the top layer?)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glPushMatrix()
    # [CODE HERE] Read the previously defined background buffer to the screen?
    for item in FrontObjects:
        item.draw()
    glPopMatrix()
    glutSwapBuffers()
```

I've read through the manual on the different GL functions related to buffers, and tried using the ones such as glDrawBuffer() and glReadBuffer(), but haven't quite figured out how to get that working...

So, if I want to have 2 drawing layers, one of which always remains unchanged, how should I operate the buffers to do that, maximizing the program's performance?

I'd appreciate if you could provide an example code based on what I've posted above!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. However unless your rendering is very, very, *VERY* complicated, this kind of caching often isn't worth the time it takes to implement it.

> It's mostly intended for use with large screen resolution and a relatively slow computer, so, while it's all working fine, it could use some performance gain by optimizing the graphics.

I'm pretty sure, that you can vastly improve performance by switching to modern OpenGL programming techniques. For example look for any occurances of `glBegin(…); … glEnd();` blocks: *Get rid of those, those are performance killers!* Use *vertex arrays* in *vertex buffer objects* instead (or you can use *display lists* if you don't want to use modern OpenGL, but I'd advise against their use).

If you really want a background cache in modern OpenGL it's quite easy using framebuffer objects. Create a "background" FBO to which you attach a color and a depth-stencil renderbuffer. Then you use [glBlitFramebuffer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml) to copy from the background image framebuffer to the main framebuffer.

Technically you can replace `glClear` by this blitting operation, but I recommend that you still clear your window framebuffer before each frame; many drivers use that as a hint for that a new frame is about to be drawn, which may improve performance. However the fillrate expense of glClear may make things worse as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, datenwolf! Could you please provide a code example for properly creating the buffer for the background? I'd really appreciate it!
Also, I presume I should use both glVertexPointer() and glTexCoordPointer() for my vertex arrays? (as I use plain textured quads)

Also, thanks for mentioning the Vertex Arrays - I'll be sure to look into it. Seems like it should be pretty easy to implement, since most of my objects are just quads sized by their texture, drawn with a universal function.

And, yeah, I'm currently trying to give it as much optimization as possible... :)

Comment: By the way, will vertex array actually give a performance boost if all my objects are just textured quads? (drawn with glBegin-to-glEnd, still). Or is it more useful just for the more complex objects?
Also would be good to know if it is supported by the older video cards...

Comment: @XArgon: Vertex Arrays always create less overhead than immediate mode (`glBegin` … `glEnd`). The reason for that is that modern GPUs actually can not process anything else than vertex arrays, so the OpenGL driver has to create a vertex array behind the scenes from immediate mode calls. Vertex Arrays have been around since OpenGL version 1.1 and Vertex Buffer Objects are supported by even GPUs as old as the GeForce 2 (i.e. over 15 years ago). So no, you'll not run in any compatibility problems at all.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try to implement vertex arrays, then. :) And about creating the FBO you mentioned earlier - is it done by the glGenFramebuffers() function? And how is the screen data written into that buffer? (sorry, I haven't got the hang of all the different types of OpenGL buffers yet...) :)

Comment: @XArgon: Yes, `glGenFramebuffers`. An FBO is technically a container which you can bind to textures; when binding an FBO the regular OpenGL drawing commands end up as pixels in the texture instead of the window framebuffer. I have a very minimal FBO code sample here https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalfbo – it renders a teapot into a texture using a FBO and then uses that texture on the sides of a rotating cube. This example uses only a color texture, but by combining it with a depth texture you can use this for screen space caching.

Comment: Surprisingly, implementing the vertex arrays somehow made the program run about 30-50% _slower_... (all the arrays were generated on startup, of course)
 `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
 glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT)
 glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, img.texCenter)
 glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, 0, img.pointsBox)
 glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)
 glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT)
 glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)`
I guess I'll have to figure out buffering after all. Thanks for that example, I'll look into it.

Comment: @XArgon: You went half the way. Now it's time to add vertex buffer objects.

Comment: Went ahead and did it. :) (all the "Pointers" now take data from the buffers bound before them) All's working on my high-performance PC (can't say anything specific about the timings yet, I've only used basic timing functions that only measure 0.01 of a second, and the result is almost like with my original program). But the program just didn't run on a less advanced netbook (without a 3D accelerator)... program sees the glGenBuffers function as undefined. All the libraries seem to be OK, so can it be because of hardware requirements for using buffers?

Comment: @XArgon: Vertex Buffer Objects are a feature of OpenGL-1.5 and later. The software fallback of Windows goes only up to OpenGL-1.4 (Vista and later) or OpenGL-1.1 (XP or earlier). However you can use Mesa as a fallback software rasterizer. However software fallbacks always are slow. In Windows Vista and later you also have to make sure to install the drivers downloaded from the GPU vendor website, since the default drivers shipping with Windows lack OpenGL acceleration support.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint. So, speaking of software fallbacks - on slower PCs implementing buffering just isn't going to give any benefits?

Comment: @XArgon: Well, the bottleneck is clearly the software rasterizer there. However how do you define "slower" PC. When it comes to OpenGL the HW of interest is the GPU. If there's no GPU present you actually don't want to use OpenGL at all, because software rasterized OpenGL is mostly slow. But then no PC sold since 10 years ago lacks a GPU that provides the kind of acceleration you want. And when it comes to Linux, the older GPUs have now full 3D acceleration support in the open source drivers that are automatically installed in every major Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've been looking into FrameBuffers for storing the static background, and I seem to be lost here...
Here's what my background-generating and main drawing loop functions look like so far:

```
def MakeBackground(self):
    self.BufferBack = glGenFramebuffers(1)
    self.BufferRender = glGenRenderbuffers(1)
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, self.BufferRender)
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, self.ScreenWidth, self.ScreenHeight)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glPushMatrix()      
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT)
    for obj in BackObjects:
        obj.drawBack()  
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT)
    glPopMatrix()
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.BufferBack)
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, self.BufferRender)
    glutSwapBuffers()
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)

def DrawCycle(self):
    self.UpdatePositions()
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glPushMatrix()

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.BufferBack)
    glBlitFramebuffer(0,0,1920,1080,0,0,1920,1080,GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,GL_LINEAR)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT)
    for obj in FrontObjects:
        obj.draw()
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT)
    glPopMatrix()
    glutPostRedisplay()
    glutSwapBuffers()
```

I'm trying to draw the background stored in the "self.BufferBack" framebuffer in the main drawing loop. The background just gets drawn in the 1st frame (while the MakeBackground function is executed), and disappears later. Maybe it's because the framebuffer gets cleared when glClear is executed? Or maybe the rendered background isn't even getting stored there?
(Based on what I see when I edited out glClear, the background isn't getting redrawn by glBlitFramebuffer...)

I hope people experienced with the use of buffers could point out some errors here... :) I'm pretty sure they've got to be obvious. I haven't figured out all the right actions here, and may just have totally misused all the framebuffer functions here...